# Handle dynamic dropdown laravel JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, forms, dropdown

I'm trying to make an application for my church.
When I edit a person, the departement o which he belongs are displayed. But the problem is that I do not know how to manipulate each department so that it displays the specific functions it contains. Here is a portion of code:

```
<div id="departement">
  @foreach ($chretien->postes as $poste)
    <div class="row mg-t-20 dept" id="dept"> 
      {!! Form::label('departement', 'Département', ['class' => 'col-sm-4 form-control-label']) !!}
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="selection form-control " name="departement[]" id="departement[{{$loop->iteration}}]">
          @foreach ($departements as $departement)
              <option @if($poste->departement_id == $departement->id) {{ $selected }} @endif value="{{ $departement->id }}">{{ $departement->nom }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        {!! Form::button('+', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'ajouter']) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mg-t-20 " id="poster">
      {!! Form::label('poste', 'Poste', ['class' => 'col-sm-4 form-control-label']) !!}
       <div class="col-sm-7 mg-t-10 mg-lg-t-0" >
         <select name="poste[]" id="poste0" class="selection col-sm-10 poste">
           <option value="">{{$poste->intitule}}</option>
         </select>
       </div>  
     </div>
  @endforeach
  </div>
```